RP2040 IN not reading expected data
I have been attempting to make a DSHOT library using the built-in PIO functionality of the Arduino RP2040 board.
Ive gotten to the point where I am properly sending a speed command, the motor controller is reading and setting the motor to the requested speed, and it is returning the eRPM telemetry along the same line.
However, I have not been able to read back the eRPM telemetry and WAIT seems to not work, the closest I've gotten is all 1s or a 1 and the rest 0s for a 32 bit value, and that requires me to disable WAIT. If the WAIT is not disabled, then I only get a single 0 on my serial, coming from the IN NULL. My current PIO code is based on the uart rx example from in the documentation from Raspberry Pi.
I have attempted swapping around the pindir value at the beginning of each section of code, but the TX will only work with odd values (1, 3) and the RX only with even (0, 2). If I don't use those values the respective part of code will be blocked (i.e. if I use pindirs 0, 2 on TX i see no outbound signal on my oscilloscope, and if I use pindirs 1, 3, the return signal from the motor controller is blocked).
My guess is I've made an error in the helper C code in the .pio file, and for some reason the in commands are reading the wrong line, but I'm not sure. Maybe in has an interaction with pindirs and pull up resistors I haven't found.
Below is a picture of what the signal looks like on my oscilloscope, and both the pio and main C++ code.

.program BiDirDshot
.side_set 1 opt; if set to a greater number sequential GPIO pins will immitate I.E. if 2 then pin and pin+1 gpio will do below

.define public T1 3 ; constant on time
.define public T2 3 ; variable on time
.define public T3 2 ; constant off time
.define public T4 4 ; between rx read lines

PUBLIC TX_portion:
    set pindirs, 3          [7]
    set y, 15       side 1  [7]      ; begin counting for 16 bits
bitloop:
    out x, 1        side 1  [T3 - 1] ; high time at end of bit   _
    jmp !x do_zero  side 0  [T1 - 1] ; low time at beginning of bit and check if 1 or 0  _-
do_one:
    jmp y-- bitloop side 0  [T2 - 1] ; low time for a 1, then send to top   _--
do_zero:
    jmp y-- bitloop side 1  [T2 - 1] ; high time for a 0    _-_
    nop             side 1  [T3 - 1] ; high time at end of bit   _
hold:
    jmp hold

PUBLIC RX_portion:

    set pindirs, 0
    in null, 1                       ; get first bit, slightly different timing than rest for convenience 
    set y, 30                        ; Preload bit counter, delay until eye of first data bit
    wait 0 pin 0                     ; Wait for start bit
RXloop:                              ; Loop 31 times
    in pins, 1                       ; Sample data
    jmp y-- RXloop          [T4] ; Each iteration is 4 cycles, 2 delay + 2 commands (1 cycle each)
    ; in pins, 1              [5]      ; get final bit with extra delay
    ; push                             ; send data to fifo
    jmp hold

; PUBLIC high_delay: 
;     wait 0 pin 1    side 1
% c-sdk {
#include "hardware/clocks.h"

static inline void BiDirDshot_program_init(PIO pio, uint sm, uint offset, uint pin, float freq) {

    pio_gpio_init(pio, pin);                                        // set GPIO for PIO use
    pio_sm_set_consecutive_pindirs(pio, sm, pin, 1, true);          // sets a single pin direction (inbound or outbound)

    pio_sm_config c = BiDirDshot_program_get_default_config(offset);     // default config (edited later)
    sm_config_set_out_shift(&c, false, true, 16);                   // false -> read from MSB, true to autopull from TX FIFO (), amount of bits autopull threshhold 
    sm_config_set_in_shift(&c, false, true, 32);                    // false -> write from MSB, true to autopush from RX FIFO (), amount of bits autopush threshhold 

    // gpio_set_pulls(pin, true, false);                               // up, down

    // configure the input and sideset pin groups to start at `pin`
    sm_config_set_in_pins (&c, pin);
    sm_config_set_set_pins (&c, pin, 1);
    sm_config_set_sideset_pins(&c, pin);                            // sets pin state (here is where .side_set # makes a difference) 

    int cycles_per_bit = BiDirDshot_T1 + BiDirDshot_T2 + BiDirDshot_T3;            // self explanatory
    float div = clock_get_hz(clk_sys) / (freq * cycles_per_bit);    // calculate clock divider from user input SIGNAL frequency (dshot name*1000) 
    sm_config_set_clkdiv(&c, div);                                  // sets divider

    pio_sm_init(pio, sm, offset, &c);                               // load code into state machine
    pio_sm_set_enabled(pio, sm, true);                              // begin PIO code
}

static inline uint BiDirDshot_tx_instr (uint offset) {
    // encode a "jmp TX portion" instruction for the state machine
    return pio_encode_jmp (offset + BiDirDshot_offset_TX_portion);
}

static inline uint BiDirDshot_rx_instr (uint offset) {
    // encode a "jmp RX portion" instruction for the state machine
    return pio_encode_jmp (offset + BiDirDshot_offset_RX_portion);
}

//; static inline uint BiDirDshot_delay_instr (uint offset) {
//;     // encode a "jmp high delay" instruction for the state machine
//;     return pio_encode_jmp (offset + BiDirDshot_offset_high_delay);
//; }
%}

#include <Arduino.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "pico/stdlib.h"
#include "hardware/pio.h"
#include "hardware/clocks.h"
#include "BiDirDshot.pio.h"

#define MOTOR_1 25
#define MOTOR_2 16

uint Dshot = 1200; 
u_int32_t sig = 48;
u_int16_t speed = 2000;
u_int32_t gapLeng = 37;       // approx how long after begin TX to start RX transmission, 37 for 1200, 28 for 600, 55 for 300
u_int32_t resetLeng = 150;    // approx how long a TX or RX transmission takes, 15 for 1200, 30 for 600, 55 for 300
u_long ms_last = millis();
u_long ms_last2 = millis();
u_long ml_last = micros();
bool M1_fifo = 0;
bool M2_fifo = 0;
struct motorSpeed {
    uint32_t motor1, motor2;
};
motorSpeed chkSpd;
uint TX_portion;
uint RX_portion;
uint high_delay;
int tick = 32;
bool flipper = true;
bool dir = true;
bool startRX = true;

u_int32_t spdTOsig (u_int16_t speed) {
    u_int32_t frame = (speed << 1);                                 // shift right
    uint32_t crc = (~(frame ^ (frame >> 4) ^ (frame >> 8))) & 0x0F; // create CRC
    frame = ((frame << 4) | crc)<<16;                               // add crc
    return frame;
}

// void swapDelay() {
//   pio_sm_exec_wait_blocking (pio0, 0, high_delay);
//   pio_sm_exec_wait_blocking (pio0, 1, high_delay);
// }

void putSignal(uint32_t frame) {
    // u_long hold = micros();
    // while(micros() - hold <= 1) swapDelay();
    pio_sm_put_blocking(pio0, 0, frame);              // send motor 1 speed
    pio_sm_put_blocking(pio0, 1, frame);              // send motor 2 speed
    pio_sm_exec_wait_blocking (pio0, 0, TX_portion);  // start sending signal to motor 1
    pio_sm_exec_wait_blocking (pio0, 1, TX_portion);  // start sending signal to motor 2
}

typedef struct motorSpeed Struct;

Struct getSignal(motorSpeed M, bool first) {
    if (first){                                       // only allow jmp push to happen once
        // Serial.println("started");
        pio_sm_exec_wait_blocking (pio0, 0, RX_portion);
        pio_sm_exec_wait_blocking (pio0, 1, RX_portion);
    }
    // M1_fifo = false;
    // M1_fifo = pio_sm_is_rx_fifo_full(pio0, 0);      //constantly check for full rx fifos
    // M2_fifo = pio_sm_is_rx_fifo_full(pio0, 1);
    // Serial.println(M1_fifo);

    if (!pio_sm_is_rx_fifo_empty(pio0, 0)){
        M.motor1 = pio_sm_get_blocking(pio0, 0);        // recieve motor 1 speed
        // M.motor2 = pio_sm_get_blocking(pio0, 1);        // recieve motor 2 speed
        // M1_fifo = 0;
        // M2_fifo = 0;
        // Serial.println("data");
    }
    return (M) ;                                       // send out response
}

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(115200);
    delay(1000);

    // start pio program
    PIO pio = pio0;
    int sm = 0;
    uint offset = pio_add_program(pio, &BiDirDshot_program);
    TX_portion = BiDirDshot_tx_instr(offset);
    RX_portion = BiDirDshot_rx_instr(offset);
    // high_delay = BiDirDshot_delay_instr(offset);

    BiDirDshot_program_init(pio, sm, offset, MOTOR_1, Dshot*1000);   // start motor 1
    BiDirDshot_program_init(pio, sm+1, offset, MOTOR_2, Dshot*1000); // start motor 2
    ms_last = millis();                                           // begin timer

    while(millis() - ms_last <= 300){
        if(millis() - ms_last2 >= 1){
            putSignal(sig);
            ms_last2 = millis();
        }
    }
    ms_last = millis();
    speed = 48;   
    sig = spdTOsig(speed);
    Serial.println("serial initiated");
}

void loop() {
    // ramp for return testing
    // if (millis() - ms_last >=10 ){
    //   if(speed >= 1046) 
    //     tick = -tick;
    //   else if (speed < 48)
    //     tick = -tick;
    //   speed = speed + tick;
    //   ms_last = millis();
    //   sig = spdTOsig(speed);
    // }

    // square wave for cycle testing
    if(millis() - ms_last >= 3000 && flipper){
        speed = 1046;
        ms_last = millis();
        sig = spdTOsig(speed);
        flipper = false;
    }
    else if(millis() - ms_last >= 1000 && !flipper){
        speed = 48;
        ms_last = millis();
        sig = spdTOsig(speed);
        flipper = true;
    }

    if(micros() - ml_last >= gapLeng && !dir){  
        chkSpd = getSignal(chkSpd, startRX);
        startRX = false;
        if (micros() - ml_last >= resetLeng - 5){
            dir = true;
            // ml_last = micros();
            Serial.println(chkSpd.motor1, BIN);
        }
    }
    else if(micros() - ml_last >= resetLeng && dir){  // use 150 at Dshot600 and 200 at Dshot300
        putSignal(sig);
        ml_last = micros();
        dir = false; 
        startRX = true;
        // Serial.print("filled rx fifo ");
    }
}


Oops, i had the motor plugged into pin 16 and all my testing was happening on motor 1 which was pin 25.
i also discovered the wait seems to hang up when the motor isnt plugged in, but a jmp loop waiting for the low pin to pass thru fixes things.
PUBLIC RX_portion:

    set pindirs, 0
    set y, 31                        ; Preload bit counter, delay until eye of first data bit

CHKloop:
    jmp pin CHKloop

RXloop1:
    in pins, 1                   ; Sample data
    jmp y-- RXloop1          ; Each iteration is 4 cycles, 2 delay + 2 commands (1 cycle each)
    set y, 31 
RXloop2:
    in pins, 1
    jmp y-- RXloop2
    jmp hold

also swapped the argument for the data pull to be fifo level because I increased the bits read off the line
  if (pio_sm_get_rx_fifo_level(pio0, 0) >= 2){
    M.motor1 = (uint64_t)pio_sm_get_blocking(pio0, 0) << 32;        // receive motor 1 speed
    M.motor1 |= (uint64_t)pio_sm_get_blocking(pio0, 0);

